# shorten a string

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am writing a script to read a `.txt` file and store the result somewhere.

I need to shorten the expression:

```
str1/str2/str3/str4/str5
```

I just need only **`str5`** that's it from the above.

I am reading that file line by line in a `while` loop.

How do I shorten such strings?

Answer (score 5):

The `basename` utility will return the filename component of a pathname.  If we treat your string as a pathname, it will return `str5`:

```sh
string=str1/str2/str3/str4/str5
basename -- "$string"
```

The above outputs `str5`.  This would work even if `$string` contained embedded newlines or started with `-`:

```sh
string='-str1/str2/str3/str
4/str5'
basename -- "$string"
```

Storing the result of `basename` in a variable is done with an ordinary command substitution:

```
newstring=$( basename -- "$string" )
```

But *command substitution* strips **all** trailing newline characters: the one output by `basename` as a line delimiter but also all the ones that would happen to be at the end of `$string`.

Using the `${var##pattern}` operator of POSIX shells would avoid that (and also save forking a process and executing a separate command):

```
string='very/
strange
file name

'
newstring=${string##*/}
```

But would give different values for `$string`s like `/` or `/some/dir/`

Comment: Just curious which one is better/efficient `basename` or `${string##/*}`.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv If you want `c` from `a/b/c/`, then you should use `basename`. The substitution would otherwise be faster.

Comment: thank you. 

If I wanna store it somewhere and print it later. How do I do that?

Comment: @psiloveyou See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
string="str1/str2/str3/str4/str5"

echo $string | awk -F'/' '{print $5}'
```

-F is used to specify the delimiter

Comment: or, more generally, `print $NF` to print the last element (in case there's more or less than 5).   or `print $(NF-1)` to print the second-last element, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

As you are reading the file in a while-loop, you could...

```bash
while IFS='/' read -r one two three four five junk; do
  echo "$five"
done < yourfile
```

or you could use `cut`:

```bash
cut -d'/' -f5 yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple substitution:

```
echo ${string##*/}
```

e.g.

```
string="str1/str2/str3/str4/str5"
echo ${string##*/}
```

will give output `str5`. It will also work if string has newlines.

Also it will work if you have string of variable size, i.e. you don't know how many `/`, your string contains.

Comment: echo {"\"metric\"": {"\"date\"": "\"$DATE\"","\"Time\"": $t,"\"level\"": "\"$level\""}} 

I need to input that string in place of level. How do I do that? Help me please , I am new to all this.

Comment: How do I store that modified string somewhere and then I can print it using echo??